# Calling Images in Text Posts Using Tumblr API: Part Deux

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, tumblr

I hate to keep asking basic questions and looking like a complete idiot, but until I can sit down and master Javascript and jQuery, I have to rely on you kind and generous folks here.

I'm calling Tumblr posts tagged "_featured" and showing them in the sidebar along with an image if it's a text post with an included image. The only problem is that the image itself isn't linked. Not a big deal, but a little unintuitive. How would I fix that?

And the code:

```
/*
    TUMBLR FEATURED POSTS SCRIPT
    Automatically gets all posts tagged with "featured" and lists them
    REQUIRES JQUERY!
    --------------------------------------
    Created by james <at> bandit.co.nz
    http://blog.bandit.co.nz

    Some code borrowed from Jacob DeHart's AJAX Search:
    http://blog.bandit.co.nz/post/80415548/tumblr-ajax-inline-search
*/
Featured = {
    'apiNum' : 50, // how many posts to read
    'listId' : '_featured', // the id of the ul to write to
    'tagName' : '_featured', // the name of the tag we're searching for
    'linkAppend' : '', // html to append to the end of each linked post

    'postDB' : [],
    'listPos' : 0,
    'doList' : function (where) {
        var li; var ul = $('#'+where);
        var titles = {"link":"link-text", "photo":"photo-caption", "quote":"quote-text", "regular":"regular-title", "video":"video-caption"}

        // cycle through post database
        pcount = Featured.postDB.length;
        for(i=Featured.listPos;i<pcount;i++) {
            p = Featured.postDB[i];
            if(p[titles[p.type]] != '') titlestr = p[titles[p.type]].replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
            else titlestr = p['url'];

            li = document.createElement('li');
            $(li).append($(p['regular-body']).find('img')[0])
            .append('<div class="featurelink"><a class="'+p.type+'" href="'+p["url-with-slug"]+'">'+titlestr+Featured.linkAppend+'</a></div>');
            ul.append(li);

            Featured.listPos = pcount;
        }
    },

    'getData' : function() {
        $.get('/api/read/json?num='+Featured.apiNum+'&tagged='+Featured.tagName,
            function(data) {
                eval(data);
                for(i=0;i<tumblr_api_read.posts.length;i++) {
                    Featured.postDB.push(tumblr_api_read.posts[i]);
                    Featured.doList(Featured.listId);
                }
            }
        );
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    Featured.getData();
});
```

As always, any help receives my undying gratitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're appending the image to the `<li>` when you want it inside the `<a>` that will be inside that `<li>`. Changing your list item builder from this:

```
li = document.createElement('li');
$(li).append($(p['regular-body']).find('img')[0])
     .append('<div class="featurelink"><a class="'+p.type+'" href="'+p["url-with-slug"]+'">'+titlestr+Featured.linkAppend+'</a></div>');
ul.append(li);
```

to something like this:

```
$li = $('<li>');
$li.append('<div class="featurelink"><a class="' + p.type + '" href="' + p["url-with-slug"] + '">' + titlestr + Featured.linkAppend + '</a></div>');
$li.find('a').prepend($(p['regular-body']).find('img')[0]); // The important part
ul.append($li);
```

should do the trick. The changes build the `<a>` inside the `<li>` and then put the image at the front (i.e. prepends) of the `<a>`. You'll probably have to adjust the CSS a little bit to get the layout you want, probably something like:

```
a     { display: block; }
a img { display: block; }
```

with the appropriate CSS selectors to localize them.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. That does the trick. One (more) question though: what would the "proper" way be to put a div around the link text so I can style it independently of the image? I know I could do it solely with CSS, but the code would end up redundant. Something I like to avoid.

Comment: You'd probably want to put a span around the text: `><span>' + titlestr + Featured.linkAppend + '</span></a>`. Then you can select the span with `.featureImage a span` or give the the span a class if you want a simpler selector.

Comment: Perfect. I have to say, more than anything, it's the little formatting issues that end up getting me. The power of a properly placed comma, eh? Thanks again, you've saved me a lot of time.